# オンライン学習、バッチ学習、ミニバッチ学習の違い

Tags: 深層学習

独学で深層学習を学び始めた初学者です。
表題の3種類の学習法について、以下の理解でよろしいでしょうか。

1000枚の訓練画像でエポック数20の場合、
・オンライン学習 - 1回の学習で全てのデータを使用するため、1エポック内で学習は1回
・バッチ学習 - 1枚ずつ重みの更新をするため、1エポック内で学習は1000回
・ミニバッチ学習 - バッチサイズ10の場合、訓練画像は100セットに分けられるため、1エポック内で学習は学習は100回

1エポックは全ての（に相当する）訓練データを使用した学習が1回終わることと理解しています。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2):

厳密にはバッチ、オンライン、ミニバッチとは、ネットワークのパラメータ（重み）更新のタイミングです。

バッチ：全部学習してから更新（学習する順番の影響がない、メモリ容量が大きくなりがち）
オンライン：１データ学習する毎に更新（最初より最後のデータの影響が大きい）
ミニバッチ：N個（分類したいクラス数より大きい数 10倍くらい）のデータを学習してから更新

ネットワークのパラメータ（重み）は最初はランダムで、損失が少なくなるように更新する（学習）ことで、
学習データの特徴を反映した出力を得ることができます。

Answer (score 1):

バッチ学習　　：全てのサンプルデータを用いて学習する
オンライン学習：サンプルデータのうち1つだけ(ランダムに)選んで学習する
ミニバッチ学習：ミニバッチサイズを10とすると
　　　　　　　　サンプルデータのうち10つ(ランダムに)選んで学習する
全サンプルデータが1000枚だとすると
バッチ学習：1回学習すれば1エポック
オンライン学習：1000回学習すれば1エポック
ミニバッチ学習：100回学習すれば1エポック