# 時系列データの学習の再開方法

Tags: 機械学習, chainer

chainerを用いて時系列データの学習を行っております。
例えば、A1～A99までのデータでEPOCH:100くらいで繰り返し学習させてモデルを作成。
次のデータ（仮にQ100とします）を予想します。
モデルは保存しておいて、実際のA100が解ったらQ100との違いを損失関数を通してモデルに反映。
Q101を予想します。

とまあ、ここまでは良いのですが。
Q100とA100の差を学習する際、保存済みのモデルにEPOCH数繰り返し学習を行う方法が解らずに困っています。

時系列データなので、A100とQ100の差を100回繰り返せばよい……とも思えません。
ある程度学習済みのモデルなので、繰り返さず学習させていけば良いとも思うのですが、
A200とかA300とか、先の先になった時には繰り返していないことが予想に悪影響しないか？
というのが疑問としてあります。
もし再学習を行いたいのであれば、再度A1～最新のデータまで繰り返し学習する必要があるのでしょうか？

もし、ご存知の方がおりましたらご教示いただけませんでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

具体的にどのような機械学習の手法をお使いなのか分かりませんが、なんとなく[オンラインな学習手法](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_machine_learning)をお求めなのかな、と思いました。

参考: [オンライン学習、バッチ学習、ミニバッチ学習の違い](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/48021/19110)

Comment: ご回答＆参考リンクありがとうございました。
そして、説明下手で本当に申し訳ございません。

確かに参考リンク先に書かれている「オンライン学習」だと、最後のデータの方が影響が大きい旨が書かれているので。
複数回のエポックで繰り返し学習させたモデルでも、その後新しく発生したデータを追加する際には影響力が大きいので繰り返し学習させる必要はない……ということになるのかな？

うーん。実際に結果を出してみないとハッキリしそうにないので、何らかの時系列データを入手してやってみようと思います。

例えば、過去一年間の競馬のデータを集めて週末のレースを予想する。
今週末の結果が解ったらモデルをアップデートして翌週末のレースを予想する。
このアップデートの際、皆様なら１回学習して終わりにしますでしょうか？
エポック数分繰り返し学習させるでしょうか？
まったく別の考え方を用いるでしょうか？

何はともあれ、ご回答本当にありがとうございました。